# return unique row for every sequence which can be 0 to n

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a requirement where I need to group all the rows which are in a sequence. So sequence can be for 2015 dates

```
instr_id    unit    typ         date         market     seq
Mht4o.jI01  26.55   ASKED       24-FEB-15   NYSE000000  0
Mht4o.jI01  26.55   ASKED       26-FEB-15   NYSE000000  1
Mht4o.jI01  26.55   ASKED       27-FEB-15   NYSE000000  2
Mht4o.jI01  26.3    BID         24-FEB-15   NYSE000000  0
Mht4o.jI01  26.3    BID         26-FEB-15   NYSE000000  1
Mht4o.jI01  26.55   ASKED       06-MAR-15   NYSE000000  0
Mht4o.jI01  26.55   ASKED       07-MAR-15   NYSE000000  1
```

I want the sql to return only 3 rows, first three rows for ASKED are part of the same sequence so should be merged into 1 row, then 1 row for BID and the last 2 rows are part of the same sequence so should be merged into 1 row. Also notice that no row is inserted on a weekend.

result should look like this for the above data

```
instr_id    typ   start date end date     MAX(seq)
Mht4o.jI01  ASKED 24-FEB-15  27-FEB-15      2
Mht4o.jI01  BID   24-FEB-15  26-FEB-15      1
Mht4o.jI01  ASKED 06-MAR-15  07-MAR-15      1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What two rows do you want returned?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear in my initial question. I have updated the question

Comment: Shoudnt your first sequnce be 30 -31?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is exactly as presented, with the sequence numbers against the dates (and not something we'd have to generate as part of the query) then you could use [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) to work out the groupings:

```
with sample_data as (select to_date('30/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 seq from dual union all
                     select to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 seq from dual union all
                     select to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 seq from dual union all
                     select to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 0 seq from dual union all
                     select to_date('05/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 seq from dual union all
                     select to_date('06/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 seq from dual union all
                     select to_date('07/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 seq from dual)
-- end of mimicking your example data in a table called "sample_data". See SQL below:
select min(dt) start_date,
       max(dt) end_date,
       max(seq) max_sequence
from   (select dt,
               seq,
               row_number() over (order by dt) - seq grp
        from   sample_data)
group by grp;

START_DATE END_DATE   MAX_SEQUENCE
---------- ---------- ------------
30/07/2015 03/08/2015            2
04/08/2015 07/08/2015            3
```

---

And with your updated data, it's still pretty simple:

```
with sample_data as (select 'Mht4o.jI01' instr_id, 26.55 unit, 'ASKED' typ, to_date('24/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'NYSE000000' market, 0 seq from dual union all
                     select 'Mht4o.jI01' instr_id, 26.55 unit, 'ASKED' typ, to_date('26/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'NYSE000000' market, 1 seq from dual union all
                     select 'Mht4o.jI01' instr_id, 26.55 unit, 'ASKED' typ, to_date('27/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'NYSE000000' market, 2 seq from dual union all
                     select 'Mht4o.jI01' instr_id, 26.3 unit, 'BID' typ, to_date('24/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'NYSE000000' market, 0 seq from dual union all
                     select 'Mht4o.jI01' instr_id, 26.3 unit, 'BID' typ, to_date('26/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'NYSE000000' market, 1 seq from dual union all
                     select 'Mht4o.jI01' instr_id, 26.55 unit, 'ASKED' typ, to_date('06/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'NYSE000000' market, 0 seq from dual union all
                     select 'Mht4o.jI01' instr_id, 26.55 unit, 'ASKED' typ, to_date('07/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 'NYSE000000' market, 1 seq from dual)
select   instr_id,
         typ,
         min(dt) start_date,
         max(dt) end_date,
         max(seq)
from     (select instr_id,
                 typ,
                 dt,
                 seq,
                 row_number() over (partition by instr_id, typ order by dt) - seq grp
          from   sample_data)
group by instr_id,
         typ,
         grp
order by 1, 3, 2;

INSTR_ID   TYP   START_DATE END_DATE     MAX(SEQ)
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
Mht4o.jI01 ASKED 24/02/2015 27/02/2015          2
Mht4o.jI01 BID   24/02/2015 26/02/2015          1
Mht4o.jI01 ASKED 06/03/2015 07/03/2015          1
```

Comment: It is slightly more complicated. I just recieved the full data and I am updating in the main question

Comment: Yes it works! My group by was missing columns..this is brilliant thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the sequences by using `lag()` to look at the previous value.  When the sequence changes unexpectedly, then a new group starts.  By accumulating this start flag, you identify the groups.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate, max(sequence)
from (select s.*, sum(grpstart) over (order by date) as grp
      from (select s.*,
                   (case when lag(sequence) over (order by date) = sequence - 1
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as grpstart
            from sequences s
           ) s
     ) s
group by grp;
```

Note:  This assumes that the `date` column is actually stored as a date or in a reasonable format such as YYYY-MM-DD.  If not, you'll need to use `to_date()` to convert to a reasonable value.  Or, you might have some sort of id or creation date column that can serve the same purpose.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear in my initial question. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Makster . . . That makes your question much more interesting.

Comment: Sorry I recieved the full data and updated it above. I tried using your suggestion but the result doesnt look right. This is my sql I have used 
select min(prc_tms) as startdate, max(prc_tms) as enddate, max(stale_prc_prd_qty), max(prc_typ)
from (select s.*, sum(grpstart) over (order by prc_tms,prc_typ,unit_cprc,mkt_oid) as grp
      from (
  select i.prc_typ, i.unit_cprc,i.mkt_oid,
                 i.prc_tms,
                 g.stale_prc_prd_qty,
                     (case when lag(g.stale_prc_prd_qty) over (order by i.prc_tms,i.prc_typ,i.unit_cprc,i.mkt_oid) = g.stale_prc_prd_qty - 1

Comment: then 0 else 1
                      end) as grpstart
              from   ft_t_gprc g, ft_t_ispc i
          WHERE 1=1
  and g.iss_prc_id = i.iss_prc_id 
  and i.instr_id = 'Mht4o.jI01'  
  group by i.prc_typ, i.unit_cprc,i.mkt_oid ,i.prc_tms,
                 g.stale_prc_prd_qty
                 order by prc_typ, stale_prc_prd_qty
               )s
     ) s
group by grp;;

Comment: You would be better off adding that sql into the question itself, rather than in the comments; it can be formatted into a much easier to read form that way!